# saving and then displaying camera photo on application

Tags: android, camera

I'm trying to make a android app that will take a picture from the camera and display it on the same screen next to the "take picture button". I've been trying to use a tutorial but it is  not working. whenever I take the picture and press save, the picture app fails. Also I don't know if it would display the photo on screen if I saved it. However, I am not sure of this since it always breaks after I press save.
Does anybody have any suggestions to help me save and display the photo on screen?
Thanks

Here's my xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.pictureproject.MainActivity" 
    android:orientation ="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_camera"
        android:text="@string/button_camera" 

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageView
android:id = "@+id/image_camera"
android:contentDescription="@string/image_cd_camera"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height = "wrap_content"      
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

and Heres my java:

```
package com.example.pictureproject;

import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static String logtag ="CameraApp8";
    private static int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;
    private Uri imageUri;


     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        Button cameraButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_camera);/*possibly button camera 1*/
        cameraButton.setOnClickListener(cameraListener);
    }
    private OnClickListener cameraListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            takePhoto(v);
        }
    };
    private void takePhoto(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"picture.jpg");
        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
   startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_camera);
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Bitmap bitmap;

            try{
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr,selectedImage);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, selectedImage.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e(logtag,e.toString());
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide stack trace . and you are running your code in emulator . please refer request code or result code on activity result .

Answer (score 0):

try to add this code..

```
public class MyCameraActivity extends Activity {
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 
private ImageView imageView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); 
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }  
} 
  }
```

Comment: so I should make a new class

Comment: when I add this new class I have to add more xml to my R file. However when I save my code. Eclipse says i have an error because I edited it manually.

Comment: follow this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn376408.aspx       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity